# Is there a possibility to change dismiss dialog animation?

Tags: flutter

I implemented in my project dialog open animation, but when I close him it's closing using default animation.

My question is, because I found nothing about this, if I can do anything with that dismiss dialog animation?

Here is how it looks. I want same animation for opening and closing dialog.

[enter link description here](https://imgur.com/a/tmJ1vS0)

Comment: Is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59272847/13763683) helping you?

Comment: @Raida Not really. I edited my post with video. I am using showGeneralDialog(), but I change opening animation, I want the same for dismissal.

Comment: Are you using the `secondaryAnimation` parameter of the `transitionBuilder` ?

Comment: No, only a1, exactly like in this answer you mention. How to use ```secondaryAnimation``` parameter?

Comment: You could try to adapt [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165974/13763683) to your needs